# Why does my Rust function's parameter value change after opening a file with an I/O buffer?

Tags: rust, io, buffer

I have a function `get_computer` that takes a `computer_key` string as its parameter to find it in a file. My code is as follows:

```rust
pub fn get_computer(computer_key: String){

    // read the file
    let f = File::open("computer_stock.dat").expect("Error opening file"); // line 14

    // create a buffer
    let f = BufReader::new(f);

    // Storage for the Computer Data
    let mut computer_data = String::new();

    // Signify that the computer name is found
    let mut is_found = false;

    // Loop through the lines
    for lines in f.lines(){

        // Get the string from the line
        let lines = lines.unwrap();

        // Check if it's the end of the computer's information
        if is_found && lines.trim() == ";"{
            break;
        }

        // If we found the computer, change the is_found state.
        if lines == computer_key{
            is_found = true;
        }else{
            // Otherwise, continue
            continue;
        }

        if is_found{
            computer_data.push_str(&lines);
        }
    }
    println!("{}", computer_data);

}
```

However, for some reason, when I debug it, the `computer_key` changes its value to `""` after `Line 14`. My main function does nothing but a simple call to it:

```rust
fn main(){
    get_computer(String::from("Computer Name A"))
}
```

Why is this happening? does opening a file does something to `computer_key`?

I can solve this problem by cloning the `computer_key` before `Line 14`. However, I would prefer to not do it.

Even if I just tried to do `println!("{}", computer_key);` before `Line 14`, the `computer_key` would also get consumed for some reason. Maybe it's about my imports?

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};`
```

---

After more testing, what I've found out is that `computer_key` didn't get consumed. I tested a new project with this code:

```rust
// Just to test if it's about the imports
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

pub fn get_computer(computer_key: String){
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    if computer_key == "Computer Name A"{
        println!("YES");
    }

}

fn main(){
    get_computer(String::from("Computer Name A"))
}
```

After Debugging, `YES` is printed out in the terminal, yet in the VSCode Debugger Variable View, it contains `""`. Unless I put it into the `watch lists` it appears correctly.

I don't know why but it's the debugger's or the [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) fault. I don't know what's happening, but I'm using CodeLLDB in Visual Studio Code. Is there some resources or link?

Comment: Can you show your **whole** code and your debugging steps? Variables just don't "change value" on their own. Especially in Rust, where they are immutable by default.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I'm not really sure but It's the problem of either the VsCode or CodeLLDB. I'm not that knowledgeable enough to know what really is wrong, so I can't provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

> After more testing, what I've found out is that computer_key didn't
> get consumed. I tested a new project with this code:

Here's what I see:

[image]

Are you setting a breakpoint somewhere? After the program runs to completion, I wouldn't expect any variables to have any values, and I notice that vscode won't even list the variable names under VARIABLES.

The only way I can get the debugger to show an empty string, `""`, for a variable is if I do something like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

pub fn get_computer(computer_key: String){
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    println!("{}", computer_key);
    if computer_key == "Computer Name A"{
        println!("YES");
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut my_arg = String::new();
    my_arg.push_str("Computer Name B");  //ADD BREAKPOINT TO THIS LINE 
    get_computer(my_arg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I put my breakpoint on `Line 8` where the if-else is. Upon checking today, it still does the same thing. `computer_key` still changes to `""` after the execution of the first line in a function. I guess this is my vscode problem. I'll try to reinstall by debugger or my vscode.

Comment: @BeepBoopBit, Try putting the break point on line 5  (first line of function).  Is the value of `computer_key` still an empty string?  Then use the debugger controls and Step Over line by line to see if you can detect any change in the value of `computer_key`

Comment: When I put the breakpoint at line 5, the `computer_key` still has its value. However, after stepping over the line (F10) it would then change into `"".` It may be helpful to say that when I press `Step Over` for the first time inside of the function (Line 5) it wouldn't do anything and just stay on the line (as if it's processing something first), however, after pressing `Step Over` again, then it would now continue on the next line (Line 6) and change the value (in the debugger) to `""`

Comment: @BeepBoopBit, When I hit `Step Over` on line 5, the debugger moves to the next line without hesitation.  What happens if you run the debugger with a break point on line 5, then you hit `Step Into`?

Comment: It goes in an assembly file (?) called `@core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1`

Comment: @BeepBoopBit, When I click on `Step Into`, the debugger doesn't go into the printlin!(), rather it moves to the next line.  I can keep on clicking on `Step Into` until I hit the closing `}` in main(), then on the next click of `Step Into` the debugger jumps into assembly or whatever it is. I can't figure out what's going on.  Sorry.